# Derivate with xml and xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, data-driven

I need to code a symbolic derivator with xml and xslt. So I created a tree of math functions in xml and xslt has to derivate each expression of the function. For example: "y = 2x^2 + 3x^5" So "dy/dx= (2*2)x^(2-1) + (3*5)^(5-1) = 4x + 15x^4" and xml would be like this:

```
<function>
    <expression>
        <coefficient>2</coefficient>
        <variable>x</variable>
        <exponent>2</exponent>
        <sign>+</sign> <!-- Sign operating with the next expression (+,-,x,/) -->
    </expression>
    <expression>
        <coefficient>3</coefficient>
        <variable>x</variable>
        <exponent>5</exponent>
        <sign></sign>
    </expression>
</function>
```

The problem I have is that I want to declare a variable i in xslt so when expression[i]/sign="+" it performs the chain rule and i=i+1 so it goes to the next expression, I can do this with a `for-each`, but when expression[i]/sign="x" I need to perform the product rule and jump two steps so i=i+2, because if i=3 then "expression[3] x expression[4]", so I dont want to derivate again expression[4]. So how can I do this with xslt because i can't modify the value of the variable? And if I would want to express 4x^3(5x^2+2x^7) then I must change my xml structure and how could be the xslt code?

Comment: Why is the second `sign` element empty? Was that a mistake? Or is a default implied?

Comment: I let the second sign element empty because it is not any other expression next, if there would be a third expression i would have to write a sign that operates with the third expression. I need to use xslt 1.0 but what is the difference? Could you explain me a little your xslt code?

Comment: The xsl:for-each-group is XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 only. Consider upgrading your XSLT engine. What is the context? Is this for web, or .NET or what?

Comment: Thanks, what program do you recommend me to use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0? Well, it is only a school exercise and im using http://www.w3schools.com editor so I think it only supports 1.0

Comment: Please take note of the StackOverflow policy on homework: `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`

Comment: For small pieces of academic work, just google for online xslt processors. There are plenty that are for free, and offer XSLT 2. For larger pieces of academic work, you can use Saxon HE. For commercial, just google.

Comment: Did you need an explanation of how the style-sheet works? All is it all fine?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed XSLT 2.0. Let me know if otherwise.

This stylesheet only works with binomial expressions, and only with sign values of '+' or '-'.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 

<xsl:template match="function">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="expressions" as="element(expression)*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="expression" mode="differentiate"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$expressions" group-by="concat(variable,'^',exponent)">
      <xsl:sort select="exponent" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
      <expression>
        <xsl:variable name="signed-coefficient" select="sum(coefficient)" />
        <coefficient><xsl:value-of select="abs( $signed-coefficient)" /></coefficient>
        <variable><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/variable" /></variable>
        <exponent><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/exponent" /></exponent>
        <sign><xsl:value-of select="if ($signed-coefficient ge 0) then '+' else '-'" /></sign>
      </expression> 
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="expression" mode="differentiate">
  <xsl:copy>
    <coefficient><xsl:value-of select="
      for $x in coefficient * exponent return
        if (sign = '-') then - $x
                        else   $x" /></coefficient>
    <variable><xsl:value-of select="variable" /></variable>
    <exponent><xsl:value-of select="exponent - 1" /></exponent>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could easily extend this solution to include other forms of expressions (and other values for sign), by adding templates, with each template dealing with a different differentiation rule (eg Chain Rule, Product Rule etc.)